# Creacion de arreglos de diferentes tamaños en todas sus dimensiones - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo la duda sobre como crear arreglos por decirlo de una manera "disparejos" como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
  int[][] matriz3 = new int[][] {
            new int[]{1,1,1,2},
            new int[]{ 1,2 },
            new int[]{ 1,3,4,5,6,7}
        };
```

Esto equivale a hacer algo asi :
{{1,1,1,2},{ 1,2 },{ 1,3,4,5,6,7}}

Como ven es un arreglo que contiene 3 arreglos dentro, que a su vez el primero con tiene 3 elementos, el segundo 2 y el tercero 6.

Mi duda es ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto con una sintaxis menos compleja?

ACLARO no busco esta SINTAXIS

```
int[,] arreglo = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2,3 }, { 1, 2,3 } };
```

Por que lo que tiene es que al declarar [2,3] se deben repetar los espacios reservados por ej no podria pasar esto {{1,2,3},{1,2}}.

Comment: Según la documentación de microsoft no, aunque puedes omitir `new int[][]` y usar la forma de inicialización corta.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El comentario que te dejaron es la razon de esto.

En realidad, en las dos cosas que estas mostrando, no estas definiendo lo mismo.

En tu segunda version:

```
int[,] arreglo = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2,3 }, { 1, 2,3 } };
```

Estas en realidad construyendo una matriz de NXM... por eso, le tenes que decir cuantas filas y cuantas columnas tiene.

En la primera version:

```
int[][] matriz3 = new int[][] {
        new int[]{1,1,1,2},
        new int[]{ 1,2 },
        new int[]{ 1,3,4,5,6,7}
    };
```

Estras construyendo un vector de vectores, que es otra cosa. En cada fila, no hay una determinada cantidad de elementos, si no otro vector. por eso te obliga a inicializar cada vector interno.

Aprovechando el [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) que te paso brian en los comentarios, hay una forma un poquito mas corta para declarar esto, aunque no cambia mucho lo que se ve.

```
int[][] jaggedArray3 = 
{
    new int[] {1,3,5,7,9},
    new int[] {0,2,4,6},
    new int[] {11,22}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No tengo el vs a la mano pero supongo que esto podría funcionar:

```
int [][] matriz3 = {
    new [] { 1,1,1,2 },
    new [] { 1,2 },
    new [] { 1,3,4,5,6,7 }
};
```